# How to cache the model Repository results

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following Repository method which retrive the current Active Directory users :-

```
public List<DomainContext> GetADUsers(string term=null)
{
    List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WIN-SPDEV"))
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();



        foreach (Principal p in searchResults)
        {
           if (term == null || p.SamAccountName.ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper()))
           {
            DomainContext dc = new DomainContext();
            dc.DisplayName = p.DisplayName;
            dc.UserPrincipalName = p.UserPrincipalName;
            dc.Name = p.Name;
            dc.SamAccountName = p.SamAccountName ;
            dc.DistinguishedName =     p.DistinguishedName;

            results.Add(dc);

        }}
    }
    return results;
}
```

So as the AD users , does not change frequently  so i need to cache the result of this method for around 2 hours. so any call to this method should not call the Active Directory ? I am actually trying to implement the same logic as for the `[OutputCache]` defined on the Action methods.
Regards

Comment: Mentioning `[OutputCache]`, why not use it to decorate the Action that returns your Active Directory users?

Comment: There is no specified action method that returns the active directory. it is a method inside the Repository Model class.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a bit hard to code the whole solution for you I will point to the [Microsoft Patterns & Practices Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649918.aspx).

Read the documentation, the implementation you need should be pretty straightforward.

I hope it helps!

Edit:

I found a more up to date documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953179%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx